# domain controller

Tags: windows, active-directory

is it possible that 2 separate domain controller(2003,2008)will work in single domain?

Answer (score 3):

Yes this will work just fine. You will not, however, be able to take advantage of anything that *requires* Windows 2008 active directory.

Comment: Ensure the domain level is operating at mixed mode and not 2008 otherwise anything below 2008 will not work